# Component with v-for not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to include a component with `v-for`. The data source `infoTexts` is an Object containing the locale code as a key and the message as value.
Example:

```
{
    nl: 'Text in Dutch',
    fr: 'Text in French',
    en: 'Text in English'
}
```

Below is my code that I use to include the components:

```
<text-editor v-for="(value, index) in infoTexts" :key="index" :database-message-contents="value" :message-locale-code="index"></text-editor>
```

Both `database-message-contents` and `message-locale-code` are props on the `text-editor` component.

I don't receive any error message in my console, but the `text-editor` is not showing up.

Comment: There must be something else that is wrong with your code (possibly with your component).  [Here's a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/bm89s6wy/) with the data you provided that works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue involved a misunderstanding with the life cycle of Vue.
I was creating the `infoTexts` in the `mounted` method. Relocating it to the `created` method solved the issue.

Comment: I actually have the same question, this answer should be voted up top. Understanding Vue's life cycle is a very big help!

Comment: This solved the problem for me when nothing else did!  

(edit: To clarify, for me it was just the declaration of the v-for items in the data() object. When I moved that logic to the create() method - or the mounted() one - the matter was solved.)

Answer (score 3):

**Your own answer to your problem ist only partially true and can mislead other users.**

Let me explain why:

- The root of this problem doesn't lie in using the wrong Vue lifecycle methods
- **v-for** itself **is reactive** which means you can add an element at any point during the lifecycle and it would just re-render.

Assumed code in your `mounted`method:

```
this.infoTexts.nl = 'Text in Dutch'
```

This code does not work because **Vue cannot detect properties added to objects at runtime**.

What you should be doing instead is using the [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) method provided.
So your new code would look something like this.

```
Vue.set(this.infoTexts, 'nl', 'Text in Dutch');
```

Using the code above you can add new languages whenever you want and in whatever lifecycle method you want.

Even if you didn't provide the code showing the creation of your `infoTexts` array this is causing the problem 95% of the time.